# R - Why are my fgsea adjusted p values all the same?

Tags: r, p-value

I have some differential expression data from RNAseq generated by `DESeq2`.

I ran these data with the `fgsea` package using the Hallmark MSigDB signatures. However, I've noticed that in the table of results (picured below) that all the adjusted p-values are the same for the first few pages, although the unadjusted p-values are different.

Is there a reason why `padj` are all the same or have I gone wrong somewhere?

Thanks!

[image: Results table of fgsea analysis]

Comment: It's correct. The adjusted p-values gives you the lowest FDR this entry will pass. You can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate on the the FDR is calculated

Comment: The p-values you see there, they are pretty close, so they will be pretty close in terms of P < k/m * alpha

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is something to do more with statistics than programming. I suggest you that you try to adjust them "by hand". You can use the function `p.adjust()` of R. If your results are stored in a dataframe called `all`, just try this:

```
p.unadjusted <- all$pval
p_adjusted <- p.adjust(p.unadjusted, method = "BH")
```

If this gives different results for each adjusted p-value, then there is something more going on.

Comment: it is correct. Even if you do p.adjust(..,) it always returns the lowest FDR the entry will pass.

Comment: Try this  set.seed(111);p.adjust(c(0.001,0.001,runif(20))) , you'll see what I mean. Try not to assume until you have checked the code or the package

Comment: @StupidWolf I've done it with the Benjamini-Hochberg method and I don't get the same adjusted p-values...

Comment: can you elaborate on that? what did you do with p.adjust(..,method=" BH") ? Is it that you run fgsea and then compared the adjusted pvalues provided by the package with the ones you adjusted with p.adjust ?

Answer (score 0):

1. It's normal to have identical adjusted P-values depending on the nominal p-values. For, example:

```
> p.adjust(c(0.1, 0.01, 0.015, 0.02), method = "BH")
[1] 0.10000000 0.02666667 0.02666667 0.02666667
```

2. One of the reasons you have identical adjusted P-values is that many P-values reached `1/nperm` limit. Increasing `nperm` will get you higher resolution and there will be smaller number of identical adjusted P-values. Additionally, in the latest releases of `fgsea` the core algorithm have changed and arbitrarily low P-values can be calculated, after which identical adjusted P-values will be minimal.